# Why should i add the butter after i knead the main ingredients when making a bread?

Tags: bread

Why should i add the butter after i knead the main ingredients when making a bread? i saying this because from this recipe https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDAznRsfPjo and many others that i have seen, they have added the butter after kneading (or mixing though), i just realized this in few bread recipes like that one, so which its the purpose of mixing it like that, this kinda reminds me of when you make puff pastry dough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a yeast-risen bread, like the banana bread video you linked to, it's important that the liquids in the recipe are allowed to properly hydrate the flour particles. This is so that the gluten proteins present in wheat flour can start to develop the gluten network needed to contain the gases produced by the yeast. If you add fats such as oil or butter along with the other wet ingredients, they can coat the flour particles and prevent them from getting the moisture they need.

Answer (score 2):

Butter and other fats are known to inhibit gluten formation. To be able control that, adding the butter once some of the gluten networks are formed seems to be the reason why.